# Salesforce Security Review?

Tags: security

i have used the burp tool but i think it doesent suit for my requirements.. can i know what are the different parammeters on which code is being reviewed apart from governor limits and sharing rules...i am having callouts in my apex whose response is appended in respective records...also do i need to use Burp Tool for testing..i have used the CheckMarx..with just 4 warnings with severity low...
m waiting for your thoughts...

Comment: why negative vote without comment?

Comment: I think its valid question.

Answer (score -1):

You need to clear all warnings and get clean Checkmask report.

Burp scan is required for any web application or API which is not on SFDC.

Comment: okay AtulRajguru9 is there any other tool to scan my apex prior to sending it to security review

Comment: There are other tools for scanning your code but they are not required.

Comment: why negative vote without comment?